# Projecting hierarchies with AutoMapper+QueryableExtensions

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper, iqueryable

I'm trying to project a hierarchy of entities to some DTOs using AutoMapper. I'm using EntityFramework Core (latest stable version to date).

The hierarchy is really simple:

I have a **Calculation** that has a **collection of Parameters**. **Parameters** optionally have a Calculation, hence the recursion.

```
class Calculation 
{
   int Id {get; set; }
   ICollection<Parameter> Parameters { get; set }
}

class Parameter
{
   int Id {get; set; }
   Calculation Calculation { get; set }
}
```

I would like to project this to a tree like

```
Calc1
    Param1
    Param2
    Param3
       Calc2
          Param4
          Param4
```

I've defined AutoMapper maps for both `Calculation` and `Parameter`, but when I project the root Entity, I only get the first level of the hierarchy.

How do I make AutoMapper recurse projections automatically? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If that's an EF model `calc.Parameters().First().Calculation == calc` will always be true.

Comment: I've configured EF to avoid that situation :) I have the Parent Calculation and the Child Calculation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hierarchical queries are *possible* with `ProjectTo` but generally discouraged. Remember, `ProjectTo` only creates a LINQ `Select` expression. We can't create an infinite depth of projections, so you'll want to tell AutoMapper a `MaxDepth` when you configure the map for building out the hierarchy.

In practice, we do one of two things:

- Explicitly model the hierarchy levels (ParentDto, GrandParentDto) for the depth we want
- Use recursive CTEs to create a flat list of the entire hierarchy, then re-assemble the hierarchy in-memory

The latter won't use AutoMapper at all, but at least results in SQL that won't make your eyes bleed.